# Received email from PHP contact form displays the text "array" where the input text should be

Tags: php, arrays, forms, email, contacts

I have setup a contact page on my site but when I receive emails from the contact form the user input data is missing and replaced by the word "array". i.e.

> Received Email content:
>
> Contact Form:
>
> Name: Array
>
> Email: Array
>
> Message: Array
>
> URL of contact page:
>   http://www.jsladvancedmarketing.co.uk/contact.html

I am a novice when it comes to PHP so I am unsure if I have overlooked something that may be simple to some of you pro's.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I have included my code below. Thank you in advance.

Below is my code from send.php file:

```
<?php
$ajax = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
$ajax = true;
//we do not allow direct script access
if (!$ajax) {
    //redirect to contact form
    echo "Please enable Javascript";
    exit;
}
require_once "config.php";

//we set up subject
$mail->Subject = isset($_REQUEST['email_subject']) ? $_REQUEST['email_subject'] : "Message from site";

//let's validate and return errors if required
$data = $mail->validateDynamic(array('required_error' => $requiredMessage, 'email_error' => $invalidEmail), $_REQUEST);

//let's make sure we have valid data
//if (!$data['errors'] && (!isset($_REQUEST['js']) || $_REQUEST['js'] != 1)) {
//$data['errors']['global'] = 'Javascript is required. Please try again';
//}

if ($data['errors']) {
    echo json_encode(array('errors' => $data['errors']));
    exit;
}

$html = '<body style="margin: 10px;">
<div style="width: 640px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
  <h2>' . $mail->Subject . '</h2>
';

foreach ($data['fields'] as $label => $val) {
    $html .= '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $val . '</p>';
}

$html .= '</div></body>';

$mail->setup($html, $_REQUEST, array());

$result = array('success' => 1);
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    $result['success'] = 0;
}

echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

The code from my HTML contact page:

```
<div class="container section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ul class="icon-list list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <div class="display-table">
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <a class="magnific-popup" data-type="iframe" href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/350+Argyle+St,+Glasgow,+Glasgow+City+G2+8NE/@55.8592209,-4.2632052,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4888469cfd25ce6b:0x71e8a78954d3a278">350 Argyle Street, Glasgow, G2 8ND</a>
                                </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="display-table">
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    0141 1234567
                                </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="display-table">
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <a href="#">www.jsladvancedmarketing.co.uk</a>
                                </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="display-table">
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="table-cell">
                                    <a href="mailto:enquiries@jsladvancedmarketing.co.uk">enquiries@jsladvancedmarketing.co.uk</a>
                                </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="successMessage alert alert-success" style="display: none">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                Thank You!
            </div>
            <div class="errorMessage alert alert-danger" style="display: none">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                Ups! An error occured. Please try again later.
            </div>

            <form role="form" action="assets/form/send.php" method="post" class="contactForm validateIt"
                  data-email-subject="Contact Form" data-show-errors="true">
                <div class="row padding-xs-top">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-float-label">
                            <input id="contact_name" placeholder="Name" required type="text" name="field[]" class="form-control input-lg">
                            <label for="contact_name">Name *</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-float-label">
                            <input id="contact_email" placeholder="Email" required type="email" name="field[]" class="form-control input-lg">
                            <label for="contact_email">Email *</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-float-label">
                            <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control input-lg" rows="4" name="field[]" required></textarea>
                            <label for="contact_message">Message *</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Send Now</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a couple problems here. You are using:

```
foreach ($data['fields'] as $label => $val) {
    $html .= '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $val . '</p>';
}
```

$data['fields'] looks like it should be $data['field'] as per the name in the form? A good way to test to make sure you are getting all the data you want is to `var_dump($data);` just above the foreach loop and check to see whats in that form data. If you get an empty array then you are using an incorrect name.